# Кик определенного человека по команде

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Хочу сделать так, что бы при вводе команды кикало человека айди которого я впишу в код заранее. Попробовал сделать так:

```
@bot.command()
async def kickk(ctx, member: discord.Member=310772490861281281, reason= None):
 discord.Member.id = 310772490861281281 #ID пользователя которого должно кикать
 await member.kick(reason = reason)
```

При вводе команды ничего не происходит и вылазит такая ошибка:

```
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'kick'
```

Answer (score 0):

у тебя во второй строчке в слове kick лишняя k, может из за этого

Answer (score 0):

member это обьект типа discord.Member исходя из аннотации типов в сигнатуре метода. А вы видимо передаёте просто int (число) в этот метод. Передайте обьект. Сейчас в ваше случае member это id пользователя